# Wants to consult about select index on comboBox

Tags: c#

i have comboBox that i fill in data like this:

```
SQL = "select DISTINCT ActionNum,ActionName from ActionType";
adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL, Main.Conn);
adp.Fill(dsView, "ActionType");
adp.Dispose();
Mycom.DataSource = dsView.Tables[0];
Mycom.DisplayMember = dsView.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName;
Mycom.ValueMember = dsView.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;
```

how to select the comboBox where the `Mycom.ValueMember = 33`

(something like  Mycom.SelectedIndex = ???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx):

```
Mycom.SelectedValue = 33;
```

Answer (score 1):

see msdn  for combobox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx

```
SelectedIndex   Gets or sets the index specifying the currently selected item. (Overrides ListControl.SelectedIndex.)
SelectedItem    Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.
SelectedText    Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.
SelectedValue   Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property. (Inherited from ListControl.)
```